# Clarification on grunt-protractor-coverage syntax for rails app backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruntjs, code-coverage, protractor, node-inspector

## Background

I'm trying to use the grunt-protractor-coverage in my grunt script to get code coverage for  protractor functional e2e tests. To get started, I utilized [this tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/measuring-code-coverage), with some minor modifications and it works perfectly. Using this as a guide, I created a new gruntfile, substituting the "express" app with a rails app backend.

### The Problem

When running my gruntfile, I get the following stack trace:

```
../dummy/node_modules/grunt-protractor-coverage/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/glob/glob.js:130
throw new Error("must provide pattern")
      ^
Error: must provide pattern
    at new Glob (../dummy/node_modules/grunt-protractor-coverage/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/glob/glob.js:130:11)
    at glob ../dummy/node_modules/grunt-protractor-coverage/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/glob/glob.js:57:11)
    at Function.globSync [as sync] (../dummy/node_modules/grunt-protractor-coverage/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/glob/glob.js:76:10)
    at Function.ConfigParser.resolveFilePatterns (../dummy/node_modules/grunt-protractor-coverage/node_modules/protractor/lib/configParser.js:89:26)
    at Runner.run (../dummy/node_modules/grunt-protractor-coverage/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:323:24)
    at process.<anonymous> (../dummy/node_modules/grunt-protractor-coverage/node_modules/protractor/lib/runFromLauncher.js:32:14)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:345:11)
[launcher] Runner Process Exited With Error Code: 8
```

Tracing through the code in grunt's task.js file via [node-inspector] (https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), it seems there are two possible issues:

1. I'm missing some parameter from my config file which would correctly retrieve the files needed
2. There is a syntax issue

**Any idea why it's throwing this error?**

### My Config File

```
protractor_coverage: {
    options: {
        configFile: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/referenceConf.js', // Default config file
        keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
        noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
        coverageDir: '<%= dirs.instrumentedE2E %>',
        args: {}
    },
    phantom: {
        options: {
            args: {
                baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
                // Arguments passed to the command
                'browser': 'phantomjs'
            }
        }
    },
    chrome: {
        options: {
            args: {
                baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
                // Arguments passed to the command
                'browser': 'chrome'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the plugin was unable to locate your spec files. There were a couple of bugs related to this that have been fixed in recent releases.

You'll generally want your protractorConf.js to be part of your projects. I generally put it in a directory called 'tests'.

So your options would then look like:

```
options: {
        configFile: 'tests/protractorConf.js',
        keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
        noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
        coverageDir: '<%= dirs.instrumentedE2E %>',
        args: {}
    },
```

You could then put your specs in a 'tests/specs' directory, and in this protractorConf.js, reference them as:

```
  specs: [
    'tests/specs/**/*.spec.js',
    '!**/exclude.spec.js'
  ],
```

This would get any file that ends with .spec.js in /tests/specs and any subdirectories therein, unless the file is named exclude.spec.js.

Comment: Hey @ryanb - This asnwer didn't do much for me sadly, I have a protractorConf.js that works fine if i'm just running hte protractor grunt task, but for protractor_coverage I get the throw new Error("must provide pattern")

Comment: Right, but the issue is likely that grunt-protractor changes the CWD of the process (which grunt docs advise strongly against) to the directory containing the config file, but grunt-protractor-coverage does not. try updating the path for your specs to be relative to the project root, not the config file directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also, for me in my protractorConf file I had to change where my path was.

I originally had

```
specs: [
  './e2e/**/*.spec.js'
],
```

which worked fine with protractor, and grunt-protractor-runner

But for some reason, the protractor-coverage, this did not run. I changed it to

```
specs: [
  'test/e2e/**/*.spec.js'
],
```

and this solved my issue. Basically protractor-coverage looks at the path from the base rather then from the config file.